# Discrete values as target variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, classifier

I have discrete values in the target variable(Exactly 13 different values in total) . When I am giving that as input to Random forest Classifier ,it gives error that input as continuous. And if I give it to regressor it is predicting a value between the discrete values. How can I treat this problem

Comment: Check the documentation for the software you’re using. A continuous response variable might be the default.

Comment: What are the 13 values?

Comment: Are you sure it’s a problem that the model is not predicting an integer? Poisson regression, for instance, has integer $y$ values but does necessarily predict integers. Ditto for logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that your discrete values are non-integer floats.  The classifier's fit method runs `type_of_target`, which returns (in part):

> 'continuous': `y` is an array-like of floats that are not all
>             integers, and is 1d or a column vector.

([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L172))

(Tracing the source code wasn't straightforward; a traceback of the error from you would have been helpful.  For reference here, RandomForestClassifier inherits from BaseForest, whose fit method calls `_validate_y_class_weight` which (in the ForestClassifier child class) calls `check_classification_targets` which calls `type_of_target`.)